# Find all animals, to get the 13th animal

Tags: word-search, animals

The following 12 animals are hidden in this word search puzzle. Each of them gives a letter, which is needed for the 13th animal.

- Elephant
- Anaconda
- Eagle
- Rattlesnake
- Vulture
- Owl
- Reindeer
- Mongoose
- Serpent
- Boa Constrictor
- Hedgehog
- Buzzard

Some hints where to look for the missing letter:

1. For the mammals, it's in the heart
2. For the raptors, it's where the claws are
3. For the snakes, it's at the tail

```
    A N O M E H E K A N S O S L
    I E P G M P E N T P E L W B
    R O O S E R D E P O O T P N
    O V N U R I O E S E A T A R
    T M U T B E R N O N D O G H
    C P N L S U P E C R E E T H
    I E A H T B Z U A S L E G D
    R A E T M O V Z N G S A P R
    T S N O C A R U A S E N U R
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 13th animal is a

> hippopotamus

In the grid, in orange, the mammals can be found using

> a horse jump pattern as in chess. The letters in the hearth of the eight letter horse jump are the ones we need.

The raptors, marked in purple

> are in a V-shape, as in flight. The letters at the bottom of the V-shape, the claws of the vultures are the ones we need

The snakes, marked in green

> follow a snake pattern through the grid. The letters we need are at the tail of the snake patterns

This gives the following letters (in order the animals are given)

> AOSHMPOPPITU

This is an anagram for

> HIPPOPOTAMUS

The full grid:

> [image]

Comment: Very good! However, the anagram is not needed: Rot13(whfg ernq gur 12 yrggref va gur tevq sebz yrsg gb evtug). Do you have any feedback (too difficult/easy, too much hints/too few etc) by any change? It's my first serious puzzle, so I would love to get some feedback :)

Comment: @Lezzup. I liked the twist in the word search with different ways of hiding the different types of animals. After figuring out how it worked, it was not too hard anymore. I don't think I would have found the final animal without the hints. You might have kept it a bit vaguer, but I think it was fine as it was now. All in all I liked your puzzle